# More then one tab is not working on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a more than one tab on my page. I am getting the issue on the second tab. On page load, It's displaying all tab content but it's working when clicking on the tab.

Check the screenshot, In the first tab section content is displaying which is selected but in a second tab section, both the content are displaying on page load. I have to display only selected content on page load.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //for tabs show hide
  $(".tab_click li a").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this.hash).fadeIn(400).siblings().fadeOut(400);
    e.preventDefault();
  }).first().click();

  // for active class
  $(".tab_click li").on("click", function() {
    $(".tab_click li.current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
  });
});
```

```css
.zero_tabs {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.zero_tabs ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fafafa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #1883F0;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: normal;
  transition: .2s;
  font-size: 20px;
  min-width: 130px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li.current {
  background: #1883F0;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
}

.zero_tabs ul li.current a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="zero_tabs">
  <ul class="tab_click">
    <li class="current"><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main_tab clearfix">
  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="products">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="Services">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>




</div>


<div class="zero_tabs">
  <ul class="tab_click">
    <li class="current"><a href="#products1">Products2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Services2">Services2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main_tab clearfix">
  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="products1">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="Services2">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Simply remove the .first() from the //for tabs show hide function. However you have other bugs with the tabs staying selected in each group etc.

Answer (score 2):

I can solve this problem Please check it.
If you have any question regarding code please comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //for tabs show hide
  $("ul.tab_click li.current a").each(function() {
    navigateBoxes(this)
  });

  $("ul.tab_click li a").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this.hash).fadeIn(400).siblings().fadeOut(400);
    e.preventDefault();
  })

  function navigateBoxes(elem) {
    $(elem.hash).fadeIn(400).siblings().fadeOut(400);
  }

  // for active class
  $(".tab_click li").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().find("li.current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
  });
});
```

```css
.zero_tabs {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.zero_tabs ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fafafa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #1883F0;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: normal;
  transition: .2s;
  font-size: 20px;
  min-width: 130px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li.current {
  background: #1883F0;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
}

.zero_tabs ul li.current a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="zero_tabs">
  <ul class="tab_click">
    <li class="current"><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main_tab clearfix">
  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="products">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="Services">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="zero_tabs">
  <ul class="tab_click">
    <li class="current"><a href="#products1">Products2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Services2">Services2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main_tab clearfix">
  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="products1">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="Services2">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: Have you change anything in CSS or HTML? because I added your script and it's not working.

Comment: No, i have not change anything.

Comment: Checking again from my side.  I changed some code. Give me some time

Answer (score 0):

If you take off the first.click();, it seems to work fine here ( although it shows everything to start ). I'm not sure why you had it there to begin with.

Also if you just add this:

```
.main_tab .tabs_wrap:last-child {
  display: none;
}
```

That will keep the 2nd section hidden. What I think is happening is something is copied in wrong so instead of it saying "click," it's actually running that $(this.hash)... code which is why the first one is working.

https://jsfiddle.net/doepm6qw/2/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I checked your answer. In the second tab, I clicked on services2 and I notice that the current tab is removing from the first tab

Comment: last child css is a good idea but what if you have more then two tabs? because the last child will work only for the last tab.

Comment: Then you could either just add a class to the extra tabs you want to add the style to or do .main_tab .tabs_wrap:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

As Keith mentioned, you don't need the `.first().click();` part, but the other issue you have is that your code removing the `current` class is acting on ALL of the `$(".tab_click li.current")`, including the other tabs.

To fix that, just drill down to the one you want with `$(this)`, which refers to the item that received the click.  Since you only want to remove the `current` class on that tab, you can do it with `$(this).parent().find("li.current").removeClass("current");`

I've attached the edited snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //for tabs show hide
  $(".tab_click li a").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this.hash).fadeIn(400).siblings().fadeOut(400);
    e.preventDefault();
  })

  // for active class
  $(".tab_click li").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().find("li.current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
  });
});
```

```css
.zero_tabs {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.zero_tabs ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fafafa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #1883F0;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: normal;
  transition: .2s;
  font-size: 20px;
  min-width: 130px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li.current {
  background: #1883F0;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
}

.zero_tabs ul li.current a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="zero_tabs">
  <ul class="tab_click">
    <li class="current"><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main_tab clearfix">
  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="products">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="Services">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="zero_tabs">
  <ul class="tab_click">
    <li class="current"><a href="#products1">Products2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Services2">Services2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main_tab clearfix">
  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="products1">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="Services2">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //for tabs show hide
  $(".tab_click li a").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this.hash).fadeIn(400).siblings().fadeOut(400);
    e.preventDefault();
  }).first().click();

  // for active class
  $(".tab_click li").on("click", function() {
    $(".tab_click li.current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
  });
});
```

```css
.zero_tabs {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.zero_tabs ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fafafa;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid #1883F0;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: normal;
  transition: .2s;
  font-size: 20px;
  min-width: 130px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li.current {
  background: #1883F0;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.zero_tabs ul li a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
}

.zero_tabs ul li.current a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="zero_tabs">
  <ul class="tab_click">
    <li class="current"><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main_tab clearfix">
  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="products">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="Services">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="zero_tabs">
  <ul class="tab_click">
    <li class="current"><a href="#products1">Products2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Services2">Services2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="main_tab clearfix">
  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="products1">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabs_wrap" id="Services2">
    <div class="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, My expected output is not in the snippet. I just checked Fullpage and it's displaying all the content. I want to display only the selected tab content.

Comment: This is not my expected output in both the snippet @ReverendPete.